# Android shape drawable that is larger than the view it's in

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a View with a background of a circle drawable. I want the circle to be larger than it's containing view, but still clipped off. The problem is, the drawable size doesn't want to go beyond the view's size, and the whole circle is much smaller than I need it to be.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the circle.xml:

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

How can I get the get the large cropped circle instead?

Comment: Change the view size to a larger `dp` value

Comment: Is your desired output the second image??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

If problem still exists, you may need to use ImageView and setImageResource instead of view and backgrounds.

Comment: The <size> tag on the drawable and the ImageView with scaleType center worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `android:clipChildren="false"` atribute in the view parent and its parent.